# weather dataset

Tags: data-request, weather, uk

I am looking for a dataset exactly similar to http://forecast.io/raw/ that gives the values for London in 2015:

- temperature
- precipIntensity
- windSpeed
- windBearing
- cloudCover
- humidity
- pressure
- visibility
- ozone

I am not familiar with programming so please suggest a simple tool.

Comment: More details please. Do you need daily averages? Is the only problem with forecast.io that you need a easier tool or more open data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need the daily average, thanks.

Comment: You're not interested to learn a little programming?

Comment: ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ is a good source for lots of weather data, including what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the [forecast.io](http://forecast.io) then there is [a page](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2) with examples and ready codes for many software including R, C, PHP android and many others, see [here](https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2) for a complete list.

On the other hand, there is a simple way of getting data without going to complicated procedure of writing codes. Just go to [this page](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/EGLL/2016/1/14/CustomHistory.html?req_city=London&req_statename=United%20Kingdom&reqdb.zip=00000&reqdb.magic=1&reqdb.wmo=03772) and select the time interval and copy the result to excel.